# regular expression for matching two ip address with a hyphen symbol between it

Tags: jquery

i have tried it using the following regular expression but couldn't match my requirement.
Can anyone help me pls.... must match the ip addresses in the below example format
Example- 111.222.222.111- 222.112.1.2 (assume) or single ip address.
here's my regular expression:

```
(^((([0-9]{1,2})|(1[0-9]{2,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|\\*)\\.){3}(([0-9]{1,2})|(1[0-9]{2,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|\\*)$) | ^((([0-9]{1,2})|(1[0-9]{2,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|\\*)\\.){3}(([0-9]{1,2})|(1[0-9]{2,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|\\*))(\\-)^(([0-9]{1,2})|(1[0-9]{2,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|\\*)\\.){3}(([0-9]{1,2})|(1[0-9]{2,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|\\*)$")
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider not using a regular expression. This is a much easier and more readable problem to solve with [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var ips = '111.222.222.111-222.112.1.2';

ips = ips.split('-');
var ip1 = ips[0].split('.');
var ip2 = ips[1].split('.');

// ip1 is the array ["111", "222", "222", "111"]
// ip2 is the array ["222", "112", "1", "2"]
```

To validate them you just need to make sure there are four elements in the resulting arrays, and parseInt each element and check that it is between `0` and `255` like so (for ip1):

```
var i, temp;
if(ip1.length != 4){
    console.log("Invalid IP");
}
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    temp = parseInt(ip1[i], 10);
    if(0 > temp || temp > 255){
        console.log("Invalid IP");
        break;
    }
}
```

Do that for both IPs, and make sure there are only 2 IPs in ips (`ips.length == 2`).